# Comparing Defects per Volume

Tags: count-data, spatial, zero-inflation

Let's set up a toy problem.  Say I make a vat of soup every week.  Different kinds of soup, different volume each week (e.g. 50 gallons, 46 gallons, 10 gallons, etc.) and sometimes there are flies in the soup, which is understandably gross but stay with me.  The question is:  are there certain soups that are more likely to collect flies than others?  Could we claim with 95% confidence that some soups are different than others and which ones?

Unfortunately no other information is given other than total volume of the soup and # of flies found.  Typical defect rate approaches don't quite work here since we're dealing with defects per volume.  Poisson regression isn't a great fit for this sample data set either.  How should I approach this question?  Some toy data is below.

gallons <- c(9,14,10,18,36,44,51,47,48,78,35,53,95,133,108,22,94,97)

flies <- c(0,0,0,0,3,0,2,0,0,10,2,5,9,13,9,0,0,0)